# What means "data is completely consumed" in Node.js streams?

Tags: node.js, gulp

### Background

Some time ago, I have asked the question [What generally could be the cause of `on("end")` handler has not been called in Gulp pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087881/what-generally-could-be-the-cause-of-onend-handler-has-not-been-called-in). It was only 1 answer with copy-paste of 1 paragraph of the Node.js documentation. Of course it was not enough to exhaust the question, but the answerer have not answer to my comment with the clarifying question.

Ideally, I want to delete the previous question, but I can't because it has the awarded answer. The editing of the previous question will not attract the new answers, so I forced to ask the new one. Please let me repeat the part of the previous question in the "Experimental data" section.

### Experimental data

Below is not the working example, but If to simplify my markup source code linter class (currently it has about 750 lines) based on Gulp, it will be:

```js
import type { TransformCallback } from "stream";
import Stream from "stream";
import VinylFile from "vinyl";


class MarkupSourceCodeLinter {
 
  public static provideLintingIfMust(
    projectBuildingMasterConfigRepresentative: ProjectBuildingMasterConfigRepresentative
  ): () => NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {

    const dataHoldingSelfSoleInstance: MarkupSourceCodeLinter = new MarkupSourceCodeLinter(/* */);

    // ...

    /* First run */
    return dataHoldingSelfSoleInstance.lint(dataHoldingSelfSoleInstance.targetFilesGlobSelectors);

  }


  protected lint(globSelectorsOrAbsolutePathsOfTargetFiles: Array<string>): () => NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {


    return (): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream => Gulp.

        src(globSelectorsOrAbsolutePathsOfTargetFiles, { read: false }).
                
                // ...
                
                pipe(new Stream.Transform({
                    objectMode: true,
                    transform(chunk: unknown, _encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: TransformCallback): void {
                        
                        console.log("CHECKPOINT1");
                        
                        if (chunk instanceof VinylFile) {
                            if (VinylFile.isVinyl(chunk)) {
                                console.log(chunk.path);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        callback(null, chunk);
                        
                    }
                })).

                on("end", (): void => {
                    console.log("CHECKPOINT2");
                });

  }
    
    private onMarkupSourceFileHasBeenAddedOrUpdated(targetMarkupFileAbsolutePath: string): void {

        //
        this.lint([ targetMarkupFileAbsolutePath ])();
    
  }

}
```

When the `lint()` is being invoked externally (via public static `provideLintingIfMust`), the `on("end", () => {})` handler is being invoked.
However, when the `lint()` invoked from `onMarkupSourceFileHasBeenAddedOrUpdated`, the checkpoint `console.log("CHECKPOINT1");` reached
but `console.log("CHECKPOINT2");` - no. There is only one file has changed; no subsequent files are expected.

I suppose, I just don't know when `on("end", () => {})` being actually invoked.

The example of the console output on subsequent run:

```
CHECKPOINT1
D:\XXX\FunctionalTests\MarkupProcessing\IncrementalBuilding\01-Source\Com
ponents\Header.pug
```

Exactly one file has been processed, but `on("end", () => {})` has not been invoked.
What generally could be the cause?

### The report about reading of Node.js documentation

I have read the Node.js documentation which has been copy-pasted in the answer on the previous question.

> ### Event: 'end'#
>
> The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed
> from the stream.
>
> The 'end' event will not be emitted unless the data is completely
> consumed. This can be accomplished by switching the stream into
> flowing mode, or by calling stream.read() repeatedly until all data
> has been consumed.
>
> [Node.js Stream
> documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-error_1)

Unfortunately, it just spawns the new question.

1. What means "data is completely consumed"? On the subsequent run, the `globSelectorsOrAbsolutePathsOfTargetFiles` is just the array of the singular globs (by other words, the absolute paths of the changed files). So, the "data is completely consumed" does not mean "all files have passed `Gulp.src()`.
2. What means "this" in "This can be accomplished.."? It refers to "The 'end' event will not be emitted" or "data is completely consumed"?
3. What mean "accomplished"? It will be "accomplished" itself of I must "accomplish" it?
4. How `stream.read()` related with Gulp streams?

Also, maybe I have not searched well, but I have not found the explanation about "flowing mode" in the Node.js documentation. All I know for now is the in flowing mode, data is read from the underlying system automatically ([source](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-streams-in-nodejs/)), but maybe it is no what I need in my case. In my case, the `Gulp.src()` is being invoked from the `onMarkupSourceFileHasBeenAddedOrUpdated` - does it means "automatically"?

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the nodejs stream stuff, not so much with the Gulp stuff.  So, I'll attempt to answer your generic stream questions.

> What means "data is completely consumed" in Node.js streams?

For a nodejs readable stream, data is completely consumed when whoever is supplying data to the stream has told the stream that it's done adding data to the stream and the reader of the stream has been given all the data for the stream.  For a stream, not in object mode, that's typically done with `readable.push(null)` by whatever agent is supplying data to the stream.  For example, with a readable file stream (like what you get with `fs.createReadStream()`, it will indicate that end of data on the stream when it gets to the end of the file it is reading.

One could also call `readable.destroy(err)` (where the `err` is optional) to cause a readable to stop sending more data.

> What means "this" in "This can be accomplished.."? It refers to "The 'end' event will not be emitted" or "data is completely consumed"?

"This" in that context is "causing the stream to emit the `end` event.  What it's basically saying is that there are two ways to consume all the data from a read stream.  The first is to put it into flowing mode typically by registering and event handler for the `data` event such as

```
stream.on('data', data => { process data here });
```

Or, if the stream is not in flowing mode (has no `data` event listender), then you can repeatedly read from the stream until it you exhaust the available data and it emits the `end` event.

> What mean "accomplished"? It will be "accomplished" itself of I must "accomplish" it?

"Accomplished" means you caused the `end` event to be emitted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was the good lecture about fundamentals. I have up-voted your question, but please allow me to start the bounty to get some additional explanations about Gulp.

Comment: By the way, for the Gulp, the object mode is actual. What will be in the object mode instead of `readable.push(null)`?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD - As it turns out, `readable.push(null)` signals the end of the stream data for both regular mode and object mode.